# count the number of times an element has a specific style

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I tried to count the number of times an element has a specific class. Sadly I am always getting

> $(...)[c].css is not a function

Is jquery trying to bully me?

Here is my code:

```
// vanish the headings of the empty lists
let ulAll = document.querySelectorAll("ul.clearfix");
let counter = 0;

for(i = 0; i < ulAll.length; i++) {
    let ul = $(ulAll)[i].children;
    for(c = 0; c < ul.length; c++) {
        console.log($(ul)[c]);
        if($(ul)[c].css("display") == "none") {
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use jQuery's `.eq()` function to filter indices:  $(...).eq(c)

Answer (score 0):

The looks up on this are going to slow browser rendering.
This is an alternative approach.

First get all the html in one go like this:

```
var html = $('.parentOfContent').html();
```

Then look for the classes on that html:

```
const getClassCount = (html, myClass) => {
  const regMatchClass = RegExp('class\\=(\\"|\\"[^\\"]*\\s+)' + myClass + '(\\s|\\")', 'g');
  const count = 0;
  while(arrM = regMatchClass.exec(html)) {
    count +=1;
  }
  return count;
}
const html = $('.parentOfContent').html();
const myClass = 'clearfix';
const count = getClassCount(html, myClass);
```